# Spoof IPP response in firewall?

Tags: firewall, printer, web-application-firewall, printing

How I do to spoof a IPP "Unauthorized" response?
Have read the IPP specification documents but cannot find exactly how a IPP response should look like.
Any examples?

Basically, I have a IPP printer with a firewall in-between, that authenticates printer users, and when a unauthenticated user or a incorrect authenticated user prints, I want the user to get a more meaningful error message than "Cannot Contact the printer, please verify that the printer adress is correct and the printer is turned on".
Simply rejecting with a HTTP 403 in the firewall on the IPP port just gives that error message.

Basically, I want to respond with application/ipp and a response code of 0x0403 as a response when the firewall deems the user as unauthenticated. I have the possibility to read and decode things from the request in the firewall (seems I need that to copy over the request ID?).

Comment: So the _printer_ is not authenticating users, but the _firewall_ is? How does that work? Why not just use an actual [print server](http://www.cups.org/), if the printer itself is not up to the task?

Comment: The idea is that I have a printer which is only able to do auth by username/password, but what I want is auth by single sign on. Since the firewall does the auth task, the firewall does have the record of which IPs are logged in the network and can then permit the IPs who are logged in, to print. But I finally found a protocol example and solved the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I simply redirect the user (IPP client) to this page when auth fails. The user correctly gets a error message that tells that the user is not authorized to print on most operating systems:

```
#!PATH TO PERL INTEPRETER
$file = <STDIN>;
$file =~ s/(.)/sprintf("%02x",ord($1))/seg;

$response = "";
$response = $response.chr("01").chr("00").chr("04").chr("03");
$response =$response.chr(hex(substr($file, 6, 2))).chr(hex(substr($file, 8, 2)));
$response=$response.chr(hex(substr($file, 10, 2))).chr(hex(substr($file,12, 2)));
$response = $response.chr("01").chr(hex("47")).chr("00").chr(hex("12"));
$response = $response."attributes-charset".chr("00").chr("05")."utf-8".chr(hex("48"));
$response = $response . chr("00").chr(hex("1B"))."attributes-natural-language".chr("00");
$response =$response . chr("05")."en-us".chr(hex("41")).chr("00").chr(hex("0E"));
$response = $response . "status-message".chr("00").chr(hex("1B"))."client-error-not-authorized";
$response = $response . chr("03");
$clen = length($response);
print "Content-Length: ".$clen."\nContent-Type: application/ipp\n\n$response";
```